# How can I run custom code when a new site is created for a specific template?

Tags: provisioning-providers

I have created a webtemplate feature based on TeamSite project, but I want to add code to run when I create a site based on this template.

Any idea how to do this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Since we are talking SharePoint 2010 I would recommend using the [WebProvisioned](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spwebeventreceiver.webprovisioned.aspx) asynchronous event. This event is triggered when a subweb under your rootweb is created (note that it does not trigger when creating root site, if you need this, consider either feature stapling as Jeroen suggests, or a custom provisioning provider (CPP) as Charles suggests).

Each approach has its advantages, one of the reasons why I often for site provisioning prefer provisioning providers over feature stapling is [race conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). In short you cannot be sure when your feature is called if you have other stapled features in the same scope.

In SP2010 i tend to use CPP for site provisioning where i need code to execute for root site, and WebProvisioned event for everything else.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is rather vague but I think what you are looking for is an implementation of SPWebProvisioningProvider.  This is a class that can execute custom code when a new site is created.

More information can be seen here:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/apurdon/archive/2008/02/05/the-mystery-that-is-spwebprovisioningprovider.aspx

Comment: Dear Sir,
I am working on Visual Studio 2010 and SharePoint 2010. I want to create a Site Template based on TeamSite template. So I created a webtemplate feature, but I want to run code in site provisioning

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider [Feature Stapling](http://sharepointmagazine.net/articles/introduction-to-sharepoint-feature-stapling-part-1).